# First order decidability of rings vs Diophantine decidability

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Are there known (preferably ``concrete'') examples of a ring $R$ (commutative, with 1) such that:

$\bullet$ the first order theory of $R$ is undecidable, but
$\bullet$ the positive existential (= Diophantine) theory of $R$ is decidable?

The Diophantine theory consists of formulas of the form $\exists x S(x)$ where $x$ is an $n$-tuple of variables and  $S$ denotes a finite system of polynomial equations, with coefficients in (some subring of) $R$.

Comment: The coefficients of the polynomials in $S$ need to have some cannonical, finitary presentation in order for the question to be well-posed. Perhaps you would be content with coefficients in the prime subring?

Comment: The subring of coefficients is fixed in advance? 

Comment: As SJR notes, I guess equations should have coefficients in some fixed (recursive) subring of $R$ in order for decidability to make sense. Likewise, first order formulas are in the language of rings augmented with constants from such a subring.

Comment: We don't know yet whether the Diophantine theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ is decidable, but if it is that would definitely be a concrete example.

Comment: Does anybody think that the diophantine theory of the rationals is decidable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $F=\mathbb{R}(t)$ be the field of rational functions in the variable $t$ with real coefficients. We regard $F$ as a structure of type $(+ \times -\,\, 0\,\, 1)$. Then

1. The (positive) existential theory of $F$ is effectively computable (e.c.)
2. The full first-order theory of $F$ is not e.c.

Proof of 1: Suppose that a system of polynomial equations has a solution $\bar{r}$ in $F$. Here $\bar{r}$ is a tuple of rational functions. Choose a real number $s$ that  is not a root of any of the denominators of the rational functions $r_i$ and substitute $s$ for $t$ in $\bar{r}$, to obtain a tuple of real numbers that satisfies the same system of equations. Conversely, a tuple of reals that satisfies a given system of equations is already a tuple of rational functions. It follows that the existential theory of $F$ is e.c. if and only if the existential theory of $\mathbb{R}$ is e.c. But the last statement is true, by a well-known theorem of Tarski.

Proof of 2: A proof of the undecidablity of the first-order theory of $F$ (actually $\mathbb{R}$ can be replaced by any archimedian formally real field) is the subject of a 1961 paper by Raphael Robinson [here.](http://booksc.org/dl/1744752/01a731)  Especially, look at Section 3, "The Method of Julia Robinson." The argument shows (amazingly) that the natural numbers can be defined in $F$.

Comment: +1. Very nice! I guess you intend that the subring here is $\mathbb{Q}$, so that your polynomial equations have all rational coefficients?

Comment: Are you sure about replacing $\mathbb{R}$ by *any* formally real field, not just Arhimedean ones?

Comment: Whoops! Archimedian is necessary. I've edited. And hello Joel! Greetings from Thailand. Yes, the subring here can be the rationals, or the integers.

Comment: At least "archimedian" is necessary for Robinson's argument. Whether it is actually required I don't know

Comment: I always knew that was you, by your posts (and your initials).

Comment: Could you expand the argument in part 1? Given a list of equations over $\mathbb{R}(t)$, what is the algorithm for deciding whether it is solvable in $\mathbb{R}(t)$? For example, you are saying that there is an algorithm to decide whether an elliptic surface over the real affine line has a section; that might be true but it doesn't seem obvious to me. Thanks!

Comment: @David: The polynomial equations in question are solvable in $\mathbb{R}(t)$ if and only if they are solvable in $\mathbbr{R}$. Why? On the one hand  $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite: Give a solution in  $\mathbb{R}(t)$ we can pick a real at which all the components are defined and substitute to get a solution in  $\mathbb{R}$. Conversely, a solution in  $\mathbb{R}$ is already a solution in  $\mathbb{R}(t)$. So the rings  $\mathbb{R}$ and  $\mathbb{R}(t)$ have the same existential theories. But quantifier elimination for real closed fields gives an algorithm for deciding the existential theory of R.

Comment: I thought the equations were allowed to have coefficients in $\mathbb{R}(t)$. For example, $x^3=t$ has a real solution $x$ for any particular value of $t$, but does not have a solution in $\mathbb{R}(t)$. 

Comment: @David: This came up in the comments when the question was first posted. It was established that the coefficients must lie in some subring for which questions of decidability make sense. The OP concurred, and left it open what subring to choose, subject to this requirement. I chose the integers, or just as good, the rationals.  In any case the question doesn't make good sense if we allow coefficients in R(t), unless we introduce some exotic definition of decidability, and there are many. But then we are in territory far from the OP's intent.

Comment: @David: Let's put it this way: If we allow coefficients in R(t) then we are asking about the effective computability of an uncountable set. This should seem a little bit uncomfortable!

Comment: @David: You could ask the kind of question you are intersted in, using in place of R some countable subfield of the reals with a nice simple presentation, like the real algebraics. This leads to a complicated network of open and partially solved problems. See "Undecidability of Existential Theories of Rings and fields", by Pheidas and Zahidi, which I believe is available online.

Comment: @SJR: Thanks for this nice example. It is in a sense a bit disappointing since a key point here, as was noted in the comments, is the choice of $\mathbb{Z}$ as the subring of coefficients. In fact, if we choose $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ instead, then the existential theory of $\mathbb{R}(t)$ is not e.c: this goes back at least to Denef. What surprises me here is the first order undecidability *without extra constants*.

Comment: @Laurent: Yes it really is surprising that we get the definability of N without extra constants, and the proof is extremely clever. Nevertheless, my intuition is that the full first-order theory is in general wildly unrelated to the existential theory.

Comment: @SJR: I agree, but my feeling is also (for the same reason) that examples should be easier to come by.