# Are there any 1-decidable algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ which are not decidable?

Tags: lo.logic, ra.rings-and-algebras, model-theory, computability-theory, fields

A model $M$ is decidable if the set of all first-order formulas which are true in $M$ is a recursive set.  And a model is $1$-decidable if the set of all existential formulas which are true in $M$ is a recursive set.  [This paper](https://home.gwu.edu/%7Emoses/Papers/1998(Chisholm).pdf) gives an example of a linear order which is $1$-decidable (in fact $n$-decidable for all $n$) but not decidable. As pointed out by Laurent Moret-Bailly in the comments, by [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/130087/14094), the field $\mathbb{R}(t)$ is 1-decidable but not decidable.

My question is, are there any known examples of algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ which are $1$-decidable but not decidable?

Comment: See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129805/first-order-decidability-of-rings-vs-diophantine-decidability).

Comment: Seems indeed to be a duplicate of Laurent's question: [First order decidability of rings vs Diophantine decidability](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129805/first-order-decidability-of-rings-vs-diophantine-decidability). The question asked for any ring with this property, but [the accepted answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/130087/14094) yields a field.

Comment: @YCor Do you know of any infinite algebraic extensions of Q with that property?

Comment: I guess to make the question not formally a duplicate you could edit it to ask only about infinite algebraic extensions of $\mathbb Q$ (or fields whose elements can be enumerated, or something else that avoids the answers to Laurent's question).

Comment: @WillSawin OK. I edited my question as you suggested.